# Linear Independence of Set of Linearly Independent Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{k_{1},k_{2},\cdots,k_{i}\}$ be $i$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{i}$ and let $X$ be an $i\times i$ matrix. Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $X$ so that the vectors $Xk_{1}$, $Xk_{2}$, $\cdots$, $Xk_{i}$ are linearly independent.

I think the condition for linear independence is invertibility, but I cannot find how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposition.** $\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}X$ is invertible if and only if $\{X(\vec k_1),\dotsc,X(\vec k_i)\}$ are linearly independent.

*Proof.*
$(\Rightarrow)$
Suppose $X$ is invertible and suppose that
$$
\lambda_1\cdot X(\vec k_1)+\dotsb+\lambda_i\cdot X(\vec k_i)=\mathbf 0
$$
Then
$$
X(\lambda_1\cdot\vec k_1+\dotsb+\lambda_i\cdot\vec k_i)=\mathbf 0
$$
so that 
$$
\lambda_1\cdot\vec k_1+\dotsb+\lambda_i\cdot\vec k_i\in\Null(X)\tag{1}
$$
But $X$ is invertible so $\Null(X)=\{\mathbf 0\}$. Hence (1) implies $\lambda_1=\dotsb=\lambda_i=0$ so $\{X(\vec k_1),\dotsc,X(\vec k_i)\}$ are linearly independent.

$(\Leftarrow)$
Suppose that $\{X(\vec k_1),\dotsc,X(\vec k_i)\}$ are linearly independent. Let $\vec v\in\Null(X)$ and write
$$
\vec v=\lambda_1\cdot\vec k_1+\dotsb+\lambda_i\cdot\vec k_i
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbf 0
&= X(\vec v) \\
&= X(\lambda_1\cdot\vec k_1+\dotsb+\lambda_i\cdot\vec k_i) \\
&= \lambda_1\cdot X(\vec k_1)+\dotsb+\lambda_i\cdot X(\vec k_i)
\end{align*}
But $\{X(\vec k_1),\dotsc,X(\vec k_i)\}$ are linearly independent so $\lambda_1=\dotsb=\lambda_i=0$. It follows that $\vec v=\mathbf 0$ so that $\Null(X)=\{\mathbf 0\}$. Hence $X$ is invertible. $\Box$

Answer (score 1):

You're correct.

Consider $T: R^i \rightarrow R^i$ a linear transformation where the matrix of $T$ in relation a fixed base (for example the canonical base) for $R^i$ is X. 
Since $X$ is invertible, the transformation is a bijection. Write $v_l = X k_l$ and suppose that $T(\alpha_1  v_1+... +\alpha_i  v_i) = 0$. Since $T$ is injective you have  be
$$ \alpha_1  v_1+... +\alpha_i  v_i = 0$$

wich implies $\alpha_l = 0$ for all $l$, because this vector are L.I.
Then $Xk_1,..., X k_i$ are L.I .

The converse follows by the same argument (just take the linear transformation $T^{-1}$)

Comment: Sorry I already selected the other but yours was very helpful too. I wish I could select both :P

Comment: No    problem =) . Relax =)